# Carrierwave: rename filename / replace file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, carrierwave

I already tried multiple solutions from SO, but none of them helped me.

I have uploaded file, that stored in my folder locally. I need to simply rename it's filename (I didn't find any simple way to do this) or replace file with new filename according to whole valid process for Carrierwave (with renaming filename at SanitizedFile, Attachment model, Storage::File, etc entities).

So currently I have an `Attachment` model with:
`mount_uploader :content, ContentUploader`

And trying to use such code for renaming filename at the same model:

```
  def filename=(new_filename)
    new_filepath = File.join(File.dirname(content.file.path), new_filename)
    content.file.move_to(new_filepath)

    write_attribute :content, content.file.filename
  end
```

And when I check `attachment.content` it's still have old filename, so seems like nothing happens. So file physically renamed, but all instances of CW, like Attachment was not updated.

But when I'm trying to call `attachment.save`, I have an error: `<ActiveModel::Error attribute=content, type=blank, options={}>`.

What is the proper way to simply rename filename of CarrierWave file or to replace it with new filename?

Answer (score 1):

To rename a file when updating the model, you can define a method in your model and use the `#move_to` method from **CarrierWave**.

For example:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :content, ContentUploader

  def rename_file
    if attribute_name.present? && attribute_name.file.present?
      new_filename = "new_filename.ext" # Set the desired new filename
      attribute_name.file.move_to(new_filename)
      attribute_name.file.filename = new_filename
    end
  end
end
```

In this example, `new_filename.ext` should be replaced with the desired new filename and extension.

In case of `CarrierWave::SanitizedFile`, you can refer below

```
file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new
file.file.identifier = 'new_filename.ext'
```

Comment: `attribute_name.file` is an instance of `CarrierWave::SanitizedFile`, which doesn't have `filename=` method, so `attribute_name.file.filename = new_filename` returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'filename=' for #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile`.

Comment: I have made changes in answer.

Comment: I've tried with updated approach, `file.file` returns string (which is path to the file), and because of it I have another error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'identifier' for "...":String'`

Comment: can you try this `file_identifier`

Comment: since it's just a string, as you understand there would be no such method as #file_identifier for it. So - `NoMethodError: undefined method 'file_identifier' for "...":String`

Comment: btw, `CarrierWave::SanitizedFile` instance have method #identifier, but doesn't have method `identifier=`.

Comment: No more ideas? :(